# .OBJ doesn't export correctly

Tags: modeling, export

I am new to blender and 3D modeling completely,  I am trying to export a OBJ I created but when I do, certain faces dont show up unless you look at it from a certain angle.

Ive been looking around for a solution but can't seem to find one,  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Outcome:
[image: outcome]

In Blender:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what I did wrong, I had the faces backwards and had to flip them.